# Customizing Stripe payment on BigCommerce

Tags: stripe-payments, bigcommerce

Wondering if anyone has successfully customized Stripe payment gateway on BigCommerce.  I am trying to make the transactions into subscriptions, which Stripe supports but BigCommerce does not.  I should be able to do this via API, but don't know how to get into BigCommerce to customize...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Big Commerce does not allow users to go in and edit their code that calls the Stripe API

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to customize the Stripe integration in Bigcommerce. That integration is set in the core application. Bigcommerce's API doesn't expose any of the credit card data (so no vaulting externally from stripe either).

Comment: so when creating Bigcommerce Orders with the API, the only payment option one can specify, really, is "manual" payments? In other words, one cannot use one of the supported integrated gateways, such as Stripe or Paypal powered by Braintree?

Comment: You could list a supported gateway, but you couldn't pass any details to charge the card. If you wanted to process payment through one of those gateways, you'd need to go through the merchant control panel to do so manually or hit their API.